# alignment of elements inside a caption

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have an image review system that has a slide down caption and a slide up caption on hovering over the image. Inside the top caption I've been trying to align a review widget to the left of the caption and a few share buttons to the right of the caption. I have the elements in the caption but can't seem to get  them to align.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dottsie/nj0mgwdr/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <title>review system</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
            <script src="js/newjavascript.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/toucheffects.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
       <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">


        <header>
            <h1>Caption Hover Effects</h1>
        </header>

        <ul class="grid cs-style-1 cs-style-2">

            <li>
                   <figure>
                    <img src="http://www.ruggit.dk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/_/m/_mg_9746_1.jpg" alt="img04">
                    <figcaption> 
                        <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>


                                            </figcaption>

                                            <figcaption2>   
                                                <h3></h3>
                                                         <div class='movie_choice'>
                                                            <div id="r1" class="rate_widget">
                                                           <div class="star_1 ratings_stars"></div>
                                                            <div class="star_2 ratings_stars"></div>
                                                            <div class="star_3 ratings_stars"></div>
                                                            <div class="star_4 ratings_stars"></div>
                                                             <div class="star_5 ratings_stars"></div>
                                                             <div class="total_votes">vote data</div>
                                                              </div>
                                                             <div id="share-buttons">
                                                                 <div id="facebook share-buttons"></div>
                                                                 <div id="twitter share-buttons"></div>
                                                                 <div id="pinterest share-buttons"></div>
                                                                 <div id="google_plus share-buttons"></div>
                                                       </div>
                                            </figcaption2>
                </figure>

            </li>
            <li>
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://www.ruggit.dk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/_/m/_mg_9746_1.jpg" alt="img04">
                    <figcaption> 
                        <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>


                                            </figcaption>
                                            <figcaption2>    <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>     </figcaption2>
                </figure>

            </li>

                            <li>
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://www.ruggit.dk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/_/m/_mg_9746_1.jpg" alt="img04">
                    <figcaption> 
                        <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>


                                            </figcaption>
                                            <figcaption2>    <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>     </figcaption2>
                </figure>

            </li>

                            <li>
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://www.ruggit.dk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/_/m/_mg_9746_1.jpg" alt="img04">
                    <figcaption> 
                        <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>


                                            </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                            <figure>
                                            <figcaption2>    <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>     </figcaption2>
                </figure>

            </li>

                            <li>
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://www.ruggit.dk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/_/m/_mg_9746_1.jpg" alt="img04">
                    <figcaption> 
                        <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>


                                            </figcaption>
                                            <figcaption2>    <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>     </figcaption2>
                </figure>

            </li>
                            <li>
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://www.ruggit.dk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/_/m/_mg_9746_1.jpg" alt="img04">
                    <figcaption> 
                        <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>


                                            </figcaption>
                                            <figcaption2>    <h3>Settings</h3>
                        <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                        <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>     </figcaption2>
                </figure>

            </li>
        </ul>
                    </div>
    </div><!-- /container -->
            </div>
            <script>


// first thing added 
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.rate_widget').each(function(i) {
        var widget = this;
        var out_data = {
            widget_id : $(widget).attr('id'),
            fetch: 1
        };
        $.post({
            url:'php/ratings.php',
            data: out_data,
            success:function(INFO) {
                $(widget).data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            dataType:'json'
        });
    });


    $('.ratings_stars').hover(
        // Handles  mouseover
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
            $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
        },
        // Handles mouseout
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');
            // can't use 'this' because it wont contain the updated data
            set_votes($(this).parent());
        }
    );


    //  records the vote
    $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        var star = this;
        var widget = $(this).parent();

        var clicked_data = {
            clicked_on : $(star).attr('class'),
            widget_id : $(star).parent().attr('id')
        };
        $.post(
                {
            url:'php/ratings.php',
           data: clicked_data,
            success:function(INFO) {
                widget.data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            dataType:'json'
    });



});

function set_votes(widget) {

    var avg = $(widget).data('fsr').whole_avg;
    var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes;
    var exact = $(widget).data('fsr').dec_avg;

    window.console && console.log('and now in set_votes, it thinks the fsr is ' + $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes);

    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
    $(widget).find('.total_votes').text( votes + ' votes recorded (' + exact + ' rating)' );
}

});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: @j08691 Just had a look at it there. I'm new to fiddle and it says I have to have external sources set up in an ftp. I'll do that now and link it when I'm done. Sorry about that.

Comment: When adding to a fiddle do I use this address /webspace/httpdocs/projects.elevatedigitaldesign.com/jonas/review/css or would it be www.projects.elevatedigitaldesign.com/jonas/review/css? Not really sure how to link